# Collection and ArrayList in java

Tags: java

```
Collection<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();

a.add("Hello");
a.add("World");

System.out.println(a.get(0));
```

Can anyone explain why i can't use get() method which pre-defined in ArrayList class?

Comment: Edit title to specifically describe your particular question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why I can't use get() method which pre-defined in ArrayList class?

In Java, reference variable type decides WHAT methods you can invoke on the object.

As your reference variable type is `Collection` to which you are assigning the `ArrayList` object, you can invoke only the methods declared by the `Collection` type which are specified (look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) for API).

In simple words, `get()` is defined by `ArrayList`, but not by the `Collection` interface.

Now, if you want to invoke the `get()` method, you need to change the reference type from `Collection` to `List` as shown below:

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();//No need to specify type for ArrayList
```

You can look at all of the methods declared by the `List` interface [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and [`get(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) is one of the methods.

Answer (score 1):

`Collection` Interface don't have a `get()` method. `List` interface has `get()` method.

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();

a.add("Hello");
a.add("World");

System.out.println(a.get(0));
```

Now it will works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Print first item in the collection :

```
System.out.printf(a.iterator().next());
```

For java8 :

```
System.out.println(a.stream().findFirst().orElse("not found"));
```

[Java — How to get first item from Collection?](https://medium.com/@rasheedamir/java-how-to-get-first-item-from-collection-7b353ea6b2a3)

Answer (score 0):

If you still need a Collection Interface you can type caste and use it

```
Collection<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();

a.add("Hello");
a.add("World");

System.out.println(((ArrayList<String>)a).get(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

The Collection Interface does not have a 'get(int index)' method.

You can either declare your a as a List, or just cast your Collection to a list:

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Also, < String > is redundant, so you can get rid of it.

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
```

If you want to cast your Collection to an ArrayList:

```
System.out.println(((ArrayList<String>)a).get(0));
```